# К вопросу о свойствах русского языка (6)

Tags: орфография, троллинг

В настоящее время, "по-новому", "по-прежнему" и некоторые другие наречия образуются по правилу:

1) по Z**ому** -> **по-**Z**ому** (например, [идти] по нов**ому** [пути] -> **по-**нов**ому**)

1) по Z**ему** -> **по-**Z**ему** (например, [идти] по прежн**ему** [пути] -> **по-**прежн**ему**)

Предположим, я внесу предложение, чтобы русские не писали знак "-" в наречиях "по-новому", "по-прежнему" и их аналогах.

**Вопрос:** Противоречит ли указанное предложение хотя бы одному свойству русского языка?

Comment: @Галактион, я не возражаю, чтобы Вы внесли свои предложения. Вносите. Вот только что скажет Лукашенко...

Comment: Я не знаю, что скажут Александр Лукашенко, Нурсултан Назарбаев, Си Цзинпин и главы других государств.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите здесь:[К вопросу о свойствах русского языка (9.1)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/23714/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83-%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-9-1?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=23726#23726)

Comment: Ага, мой комментарий смотрите там же.

Comment: Посмотрел.