# К вопросу о свойствах русского языка (9.1)

Tags: орфография, троллинг

Предположим, я предложу, чтобы русские писали неопределённые местоимения с приставкой "кой-" без дефиса (например, "койкто" вместо "кой-кто", "койкому" вместо "кой-кому").

**Вопрос:** Противоречит ли указанное предложение хотя бы одному свойству русского языка?

P.S.

1. Репетиторы [по русскому языку] проклянут меня.
2. Сомневаюсь, что "дефисное" написание слова "гей-парад" "указывает на то, что два слова утрачивают самостоятельность, но не доходят до полного слияния в одно слово" "гейпарад" (цит. по Людмила).
3. Сомневаюсь, что дефисное написание слова "гей-парад" "отражает сложнейшие закономерности русского языка" (цит. по stopkran'у).

Comment: А можно я предложу писать не "кой-кто" а "кое-кто" и т.д.?

Просто я слова "кой-кто" или "койкто" не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

[@Галактион](/users/996/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD), Вас обуял бес реформаторства?

Comment: Dear Элен.

Поделитесь Вашим ответом на сформулированный Вами вопрос.

Спокойной ночи.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, с какой целью задаются вопросы такого толка, но ответ на них один:предложенное изменение написания слов противоречит структурным свойствам русск. языка: не отражает законов словообразования.Кой-кто=кое-кто (и кой-где, кой-куда и т.п.)образовались сложением двух слов кой + кто, где и т.д.(а само слово КОЙ, КОЕ -*kъ (из слова кто ) + jь,  jе), поэтому дефис указывает на наличие двух слов с их семантикой(= какой-то кто, какой-то где и т.д.).

Одно из свойств русского языка - подчинение орфографии фонетическому, морфологическому и традиционному принципам, но слитные, полуслитные и раздельные написания к ним не относятся,они отражают определённые процессы,происходящие в ЛЕКСИЧЕСКОЙ ситеме языка. Словарный состав языка непрерывно пополняется новыми образованиями путём объединения лексических элементов, существующих в языке в качестве самостоятельных слов. В силу указанных особенностей словообразования объединение лексич. единиц представляет в языке различные фазы движения к слиянию в новую лексич. единицу и тотражается в русск. орфографии путём дифференцированных написаний-слитного, дефисного, раздельного.Слитное написание закрепляет смысловую цельность с помощью соед. гласных, общей системой флексий, общего ударения; дефисное указывает на то, что два слова утрачивают самостоятельность,но не доходят до полного слияния в одно слово;раздельное - на то, что это два разных слова с разными значениями и морфологическими признаками.

Comment: @Людмила, вот вы кому это всё пишете? Екатерине? Бегемотусу? Они и так это знают. А Галактион не поймёт, у него нет для этого базовых знаний.

1. Здесь достаточно было простого: **Слитное - раздельное - дефисное написания отражают сложнейшие закономерности русского языка, и менять правила этих написаний очень непросто**. 

2. Не кормите троллей! (с)

Comment: >с какой целью задаются вопросы такого толка,  
  
Банальный троллинг/флудерство (пишу через слэж ибо мы в свое время не договорились насчет терминов). Аффтфырь генерировал под копирку подобные вопросы на английском, мне надоело отвечать на третьем или четвертом. Но там ему и плюсики не ставили - так он сюда пришел за повышением репутации - и, надо сказать, не безуспешно. Хотя, имхо, и тут торчат уши Груманта.  
  
>Бегемотусу  
  
Коли вы меня помянули... Я не знаю, что там я знаю, но повторю где-то уже сказанное. Вопросы бессодержательны, ибо непонятно, о каких-таких свойствах идет речь.

Comment: Прочёл с любопытством.

Comment: Большелапый всуе поминает груманта, а Дерзкий ни сном ни духом, ни к чему не причастен, ни в одной коалиции не состоит, один на форуме с сатанистами сражаитси))))))) Эх, вы, баламуты заморочные, кикиморы болотные, сколько вас тут на мою голову вылупилось)

Answer (score 1):

Давайте разберемся.

> С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. Толковый словарь русского языка
>
> **КОЕ**... и (разг.) **КОЙ-**..., приставка. Образует местоименные слова со знач.:
> 1) неопределенности, напр. кое-кто, кое-какой, кое-где, кое-откуда;
> 2) низкой оценки качества, напр. кое-как.
>
> **ВСЕ**, первая часть сложных слов со знач.;
> 1) охватывающий всех, распространяющийся на всех, на все, на весь предмет, напр. всевидящий, всезнающий, всеведение, всероссийский, всеславянский, всесокрушающий, всепреодолевающий, всепрощающий, всепобеждающий;
> 2) постоянно, напр. всевозрастающий;
> 3) самой высокой степени признака, напр. всецело, всесильный, всевластие, Всевышний, всенепременный (устар.).

Итак, приставка *кое-* имеет общий смысл  неопределенности/избирательности, а "первая часть сложных слов" *все-*, то есть практически приставка, произошедшая от местоимения **весь**, также имеет всем понятный смысл. Наречие *всегда* обычно понимается как **все + года** (ср. иногда ~ иного года, тогда ~ того года, когда ~ коего года). Наречие *везде* (др-рус. *вьсьжде* - кругом, повсюду, от местоимения **вьсь** - весь). Фасмер? Он не возражает :

> **ВЕЗДЕ**
> др.-русск., ст.-слав. вьсьде (Супр.), сербохорв.
> свагде, словен. vsigde, полаб. visde. Связано с
> др.-русск., ст.-слав. вьсь + наречный суф. -де;
> ср. где. Ср. также диал. **новообразование**
> ***всегде*** (севск.) под влиянием всегда...

Существует окказионализм *коегдешний* - пишется слитно. Можно предположить возникновение слова **когде** (когда + где). "Когде мы встретимся?" Что же из этого следует? Изменения в орфографии были, есть и будут, но всему свое время!

Comment: Дерзкий, я угадал, что Вы - русский?

Comment: Разве может быть иначе?

Answer (score 0):

планировалась у нас реформа, да госпожа Путина не пропустила.....а как просто бы все стало....